# Why wraps decorator is showing extra commas?

Tags: python, wrapper

I want to print the arguments and return value of a function call. We know the decorator has the ability to run additional code before and after each call to a function it wraps.

```
from functools import wraps
def trace(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args):
        result = func(*args)
        print(f'{func.__name__}{args!r}' f'->{result!r}')
        return result
    return wrapper

@trace
def fibo(n):
    if n in (0, 1):
        return n
    return fibo(n-2)+fibo(n-1)


fib = trace(fibo)
fib(3)
```

**Output**

```
fibo(1,)->1
fibo(0,)->0
fibo(1,)->1
fibo(2,)->1
fibo(3,)->2
fibo(3,)->2
```

You have already seen that I have passed only a single `args` value in the wrapper function. My question is why it's showing an extra comma in `fibo(1,)..fibo(3,)` output function and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`args` is a tuple, in your case it is a 1 tuple, as for "fixing" it, make sure you pass only one argument and receive it as `args` instead of `*args`

```
from functools import wraps
def trace(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(args):
        result = func(args)
        print(f'{func.__name__}({args!r})' f'->{result!r}')
        return result
    return wrapper
```

For `fib(3)` you get

```
fibo(1)->1
fibo(0)->0
fibo(1)->1
fibo(2)->1
fibo(3)->2
fibo(3)->2
```